# How to filter du output?

Tags: command-line, du

So that it won't show directories that contain an empty file named "0k" that I use as a flag ? It seems `--exclude` can't deal with that.

Comment: What's the name of the flag file?

Comment: Can you explain it with an example?

Comment: It took me a while to get that "du" is the program name and not a "the" article in some different language. :D I was almost going to edit it out... Pheeew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`du` can accept a list of files or directories from stdin (or sufficiently new versions can, anyway). So you can use `find` and friends to filter and provide this list:

```
find Pictures -mindepth 2 -type d \( -execdir test -f '{}/0k' \; -o -print0 \) |
  du --files0-from=- -h
```

- With `-mindepth 2`, `find` will only list directories (`-type d`) at least two levels deep (so `Pictures/*/*`)
- In each of these directories, `find` will run `test -f "{}/0k"`, which simply tests for existence of a file named `0k`. (`{}` will be replaced by `find` with the directory.)

  - If the test succeeds, nothing happens. If not, the directory path is printed with an ASCII NUL at the end (`-o print0`).
  - The way `-o` works, the `execdir` and `-print0` need to be grouped using `(`, `)`.
- `du` will then take these directory names and happily provide disk usage.

Sorting:

```
find Pictures -mindepth 2 -type d \( -execdir test -f '{}/0k' \; -o -print0 \) |
  du --files0-from=- -h |
  sort -rh
```

Comment: This one looks as an elegant candidate to a one-liner, but it seems  the test doesn't work: dirs with 0k file inside are listed. I use | head in the end to keep only biggest dirs not having 0k file inside. Using test ! -f 0k , I get biggest files.

Comment: @useful  Oh, I forgot to group the tests correctly. I have edited the commands.

Comment: find: missing argument to -execdir . Should I try using \; \) or \; -o print0 \) ? I did the 2nd : it's ok. I don't see where you use -0

Comment: @useful the latter

Answer (score 1):

If your empty file acting as a flag is called `0k`, the following command will read all subdirectories in the current directory that do not contain the file. You can of course change the `.` in the beginning of the `for` loop to be any directory path.

```
for dir in ./*; do if [[ ! -f "$dir"/'0k' ]]; then du -s "$dir" ; fi ; done
```

You've not mentioned in your question whether you need this to be entirely recursive, if so it will be slightly more complex. The find command can be used here, the search directory can be changed as above:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'if [[ ! -f "{}"/"0k" empty ]]; then du -s "{}"; fi' \;
```

Edit:
After clarification of the task from the OP, the following command should work.

```
for dir in Pictures/*/*; do if [[ ! -f "$dir"/'0k' ]]; then du -s "$dir" ; fi ; done | sort -nr | head -n50
```

Comment: Yes, recursive like `du`. Sorry, I didn't say the goal : I have to find the biggest subdir(s) being in Pictures/YYYY/. The subdirs have name `YYYYMM [DD[-DD]] Blahblah` and blahblah may contain usual characters like single quote, but I can easily refrain using slashes, back quotes, $ or so. When a YYYYMM... subdir's content has been checked, this means there is no more any subdir in it and I have dropped in it a file called 0k (zerok so that it shows on top for default `ls` or nautilus or so, as all other files therein are yyyymmdd_hhmmss-SomeText.ext, regards to exiftool).

Comment: `du ????/??????\ *|sort -rn|head -n50` or `-n20` ... is great for that, except it can't filter out the dirs I already cleaned. I tried adding the `|cut...` stuff to pass the happy few dirs through a filter that would remove all the ones containing 0k file.

Comment: I meant remove from the list, not from disk ;)

Comment: Ok, so the subdirs you're interested in are 2 levels down from 'Pictures' in different 'YYYY' directories. I think a modification of the first command will work, I'll edit a proposed change.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Vars
NumLines="5" # output that many/few lines
MinSize=0 # filter out size folders lower than (MB)

while read DUout
do
    # get folder size
    Size="${DUout%%[[:space:]]*}"

    # get folder path
    Path="/${DUout#*/}"

    # Filter out if no 0k flagfile inside
[[ ! -f "${Path}/0k" ]] && echo "${DUout}"|cut -d"/" -f1,5-6
done < <(du -s -t${MinSize}M "${PWD}"/????/??????\ * | sort -nr) | head -"${NumLines}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If every line that you want to exclude contains a certain string (e.g., file name), then you can use `grep` to filter the results of `du`.

This would be used as so: `du | grep -v -e "string_to_exclude"`. The `-v` argument for `grep` reverses the output so that only non-matches are shown.

Comment: Good thinking but I think they want to exclude the entire directory if it contains a specially named empty file. We won't know until the OP responds to questions. This will just exclude the output of the size of the file itself.

Comment: Yes Arronical, you're right. I use `du ????/??????\ *|sort -rn|head -n50|cut -f1 --complement` as input for xargs to try to filter out `du` output so that dirs containing regular file `0k` won't show. (`????/??????\ *` being pictures dir names YYYY\YYYYMM blahblah)

Comment: @useful I've come up with an answer, is the flag file name `0k` or is that the size?

Comment: @Arronical : both